# C++ Undefined symbols when using folder structure

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, undefined-symbol

I have am currently trying to understand OpenGL and found [this](http://www.videotutorialsrock.com/index.php) tutorial. I have reached a point where I would like to make something out of what I've learned so I've tired to setup a small project folder with a (somewhat) homemade Makefile. The structure of the project is as following:

```
project_root:
 -- Makefile
 -- src/
       main.cpp
       imageloader.cpp
 -- obj/
       main.o (no compiletime error)
       imageloader.o (no compiletime error)
 -- include/
       imageloader.h
 -- textures/
       some texture files
```

The Makefile:

```
CC = g++

SRC_DIR = ./src
OBJ_DIR = ./obj
INC_DIR = ./include

INCLUDE_PATHS = -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/X11/include -I$(INC_DIR)
LIBRARY_PATHS = -L/usr/local/lib -I/opt/X11/lib
LINKER_FLAGS = -framework OpenGL -lGLUT
COMPILER_FLAGS = -w

SRC_FILES = main.cpp imageloader.cpp
HEADER_FILES = imageloader.h

HEADERS = $(HEADER_FILES:%.h=$(INC_DIR)/%.h)
SRC = $(SRC_FILES:%.cpp=$(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp)

OBJS = $(SRC_FILES:%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

EXEC = main

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC)
        $(CC) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

all: $(OBJS) $(HEADERS)
        $(CC) $(OBJS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS)         $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $(EXEC)

run:
    ./main

print:
        @echo "C++ objcet files: "$(OBJS)
        @echo "C++ source files: "$(SRC)
        @echo "C++ header files: "$(HEADERS)

clean:
       rm -fv $(EXEC)
       rm -fv $(OBJS)
```

As I try to compile this I get the following output:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/X11/include -I./include -L/usr/local/lib -I/opt/X11/lib -w -c -o obj/main.o src/main.cpp
g++ -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/X11/include -I./include -L/usr/local/lib -I/opt/X11/lib -w -c -o obj/imageloader.o src/main.cpp
g++ ./obj/main.o ./obj/imageloader.o -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/X11/include -I./include -L/usr/local/lib -I/opt/X11/lib -w -framework OpenGL -lGLUT -o main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "loadBMP(char const*)", referenced from:
      initRendering()     in main.o
      initRendering()     in imageloader.o
  "Image::~Image()", referenced from:
      initRendering()     in main.o
      initRendering()     in imageloader.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

What bothers me is that the code is taken just from tutorial site with no modifications, and when i compile it all in the same folder (all .cpp and .h files in same place) it compiles just fine. I have a feeling that I've made an obvious mistake but I can't seem to figure out what causes the error?

Can someone point out the reason for why this doesn't compile?

Thanks in advance : )

Comment: It's looking for some libraries it cannot find, I can only guess it is  the glut libraries. I haven't used glut in linux but in windows I had to copy the `.dll` to `system32` directory and address the `.lib` to my source, I think you should do the same for .so and .a files in linux.

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have mentioned. The functions that appears to be missing origins from imageloader.cpp/h

Comment: Platform? You really need to include in the question what platform you're working on if you ask about build problems. Looks like Mac OS to me, but the previous comment suggests that it's Linux.

Comment: It is OS X, you're right, sorry. Yet as pointed out by xio4 the problem occurred as the imageloader.cpp was never actually compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're compiling main.cpp twice:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/X11/include -I./include -L/usr/local/lib -I/opt/X11/lib -w -c -o obj/main.o src/main.cpp <--- main.cpp
g++ -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/X11/include -I./include -L/usr/local/lib -I/opt/X11/lib -w -c -o obj/imageloader.o src/main.cpp <--- main.cpp, instead imageloader.cpp
```

Comment: I have been looking at it for hours! XD Thanks!